# C Shell Script Print Path name with Colon

Tags: shell

I am trying to print the paths that are located in a file .chsrc which is easy to print with just echo-ing $path, but I need to add something to the end of each path that is listed. Ie:

/opt/local/bin: /usr/ucb: /usr/bin:

I can not edit or change the .chsrc file. I also tried to find something on concatenating in C Shell, but that seems to not really "exist" in C Shell from what I read. I am sorry if I sound arrogant in anyway, I am new to C Shell. If anyone has any pointers, advice is always great! Thank you!

Comment: so you want to be able to 'inspect' the elements in you path by adding a space after each colon?

Comment: Edit the `.login` file so it does: `setenv SHELL /bin/bash; exec bash -l`.  It doesn't change `.chsrc`, and does leave you with a civilized shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/: /g;s/ *$//'
```

'`s/`'=substitute, '`/:/: /`'=targetPattern/replacmentPattern, '`g`'=do replacment globally (on the current line), '`;`'= command separator, '`s/ *$//`'= substitute any trailing spaces at the end-of-the line '`$`', replacementPattern='`//`'=(nothing, empty, nada, zilch;-)

Best to always echo any env var surrounded by dbl-quotes unless you want any spaces in the variable to cause word splitting in the commandline evaluatio. Especially with PATH, as space char is legal in a path.

In general, concatenation works like this in CSH

```
set var1 = text1
set var2 = myText

echo "someText "$var1     "  more stuff"$var2
# -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- deliberate, copy paste as is
```

I don't have a csh to print the output with, but cut and paste these lines and you'll see that spaces outside of `" .... "`, get reduced to 1 space, spaces inside of `"...."` stay in place, as many as you want, AND variables, bumped up next to "text Strings" do NOT insert a space char automatically, you have to put them in.

I don't see any arrogance in this question ;-)

But... before you spend 8+ years of your life using a 2nd rate shell ( ;-( ), read everything at [A great Unix Primer](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/) , especially [Why csh is less than perfect scripting language](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)